# google map info window multiple addresses via xml

Tags: php, xml, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm using the Google map code below to retrieve and plot markers for multiple addresses from an XML file dynamically created with PHP. The code is doing everything I need except for displaying the correct information in the Google map info window for the corresponding marker. I get the information of the last XML item/listing for all the markers.

I've been searching and trying different variations to get it to work, but no luck.

sample XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listings>
<listing>
    <address>123 Street</address>
    <city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
    <address>456 Street</address>
    <city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
    <address>111 Avenue</address>
    <city>MANOTICK</city>
</listing>
<listing>
    <address>777 Avenue</address>
    <city>Ottawa</city>
</listing>
<listing>
    <address>333 Street</address>
    <city>Manotick</city>
</listing>
</listings>
```

google map code

```
function initialize ()
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.2340684, -75.6287287);
    var myOptions =
    {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        center: myLatLng,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions:
        {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        StreetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google_map'), myOptions);
    var info_window = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    google.maps.event.addListener
    (map, 'click',
    function ()
    {
        info_window.close();
    });


    downloadUrl
    ('listings.xml',
    function (listings_data)
    {
        var markers = listings_data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('listing');
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
        {
            var address = markers[i].getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
            var city = markers[i].getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.data;
            var address_google_map = address + ', ' + city + ', ON';
            var info_text = address + '<br />' + city + ' ON';

            geocoder.geocode
            ({'address': address_google_map},
            function (results)
            {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                    ({
                        map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener
                    (marker, 'click',
                    function()
                    {
                        info_window.setContent(info_text);
                        info_window.open(map, marker);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the asynchronous nature of the geocoder, and if you add many addresses you will have a problem with the geocoder quota/rate limits (particularly since your code doesn't look at the return status of the geocoder).

All these questions are related:

- [Google Maps Api v3: Info window displaying same information for all the markers on the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236522/google-maps-api-v3-info-window-displaying-same-information-for-all-the-markers)
- [GMaps API V3 - Multiple Markers & InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866028/gmaps-api-v3-multiple-markers-infowindow-problem)
- [Google Map multiple infowindow does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148783/google-map-multiple-inforwindow-does-not-work)

The simplest solution is to use function closure to associate the call to the geocoder with the returned result:

```
geocodeAddress(xmldata)
{
        var address = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('address')[0].firstChild.data;
        var city = xmldata.getElementsByTagName('city')[0].firstChild.data;
        var address_google_map = address + ', ' + city + ', ON';
        var info_text = address + '<br />' + city + ' ON';

        geocoder.geocode
        ({'address': address_google_map},
        function (results, status)
        {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, info_text);
          } else { 
            alert("geocode of "+ address +" failed:"+status);
          }
        });
    }
```

And a createMarker function to associate the infowindow content with the marker:

```
function createMarker(latlng, html)
{
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker
                ({
                    map: map, 
                    position: latlng
                });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    info_window.setContent(html);
                    info_window.open(map, marker);
                });
}
```

Makes your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
  geocodeAddress(markers[i]);
}
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleGeocodedMarkersFromXml.html)