# Multiple InfoWindow Appearance in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

In case of designing multiple Google map Markers, info-window (pop-up) for displaying the content for each marker does not appears, in-spite of including  **infowindow.setcontent** method  for displaying the content for each Google Map marker.

Here is the code that i have used-----

--- here, **locarr** contains locations coming from database ---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var locarr = $("input[id$='hiddenfiled1']").val().split("#@#");
      alert(locarr);
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 13,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var icon1 = {
          url: 'images/MarkerImg.png',
          size: new google.maps.Size(90, 105)
      };

      var icon2 = {
          url: 'images/MarkerImg2.png',
          size: new google.maps.Size(90, 105)
      };


      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var InfoPopUp = [];



      for (var i = 0; i < locarr.length; i++) {
          InfoPopUp[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: locarr[i],

          });
          geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locarr[i] }, function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: results[0].geometry.location,
                      icon: icon1,
                      info: InfoPopUp[i]
                  });


             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (myinmarker) {
                      return function () {

                          if (locarr[i] != InfoPopUp[i].getContent()) {
                              **InfoPopUp[myinmarker].setContent(locarr[i]);**           
                              marker.setIcon(icon2);
                              InfoPopUp[myinmarker].open(map, marker);

                          }
                      }
                  } (myinmarker));

                   markers.push(marker);

             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (myoutmarker, i) {
                      return function () {
                          if (locarr[i] = InfoPopUp[i].getContent()) {
                              InfoPopUp[myoutmarker].close(map, marker);
                              marker.setIcon(icon1);
                          }
                          else {
                              google.maps.event.trigger(CalMarker, 'mouseover');
                          }
                      }
                  } (myoutmarker, i));

                  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

              } //if ends

              else {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful for the reason: ' + status);
              }
          });



      } //for ends

  </script>
```

Here use of setcontent is not working in case of multiple markers...... 
any help would be greatly appreciate.....

Comment: What is it doing?  What do you mean by "setcontent is not working"? Can you provide a jsfiddle that exhibits that behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map info window multiple addresses via xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278368/google-map-info-window-multiple-addresses-via-xml)