# undefined while reading array item on a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm doing a for loop to check against some values, on here is a short version. What I don't understand is why `console.log(indirizzo[a]);` is giving undefined while if I do `console.log(indirizzo);` I get all values

```
  var indirizzo = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < savedRepods.length; i++) {
    for (var a = 0; a < ids.length; a++) {
      if(savedRepods[i] == ids[a]) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var latlngStr = coords[a].split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          indirizzo.push(results[0].formatted_address);
        });
        console.log(indirizzo[a]);
      }
    }
  }
```

result if I do `console.log(indirizzo);`

```
0: "Corso Vittorio Emanuele, 1, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia"
1: "Via Nazionale, 78, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia"
2: "Via Giosuè Carducci, 15, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia"
3: "Via Perret, 11, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia"
4: "Lungomare Amerigo Vespucci, 2A, 09017 Sant'Antioco SU, Italia"
```

result if I do `console.log(indirizzo[a]);`

```
undefined
```

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous

Comment: @geocodezip i see, how would I solve it then?

Comment: @geocodezip I'm trying to follow the answer but it's confusing, should I use a setTimeOut?

Comment: `setTimeout` is generally a "Bad Idea"© to solve asynchronous issues (you might be able to make it work, but you are either wasting time or will run into  intermittent issues). Use the data in the callback function when/where it is available

Comment: @geocodezip i'm really getting confused on the callback, read the docs too. Would you be able to put up an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping multiple locations with Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and Geocoding API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463131/mapping-multiple-locations-with-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-and-geocoding-api)

Comment: @geocodezip thanks but got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480896/1018804

Answer (score 0):

This line here will be adding `a + 1` for every id. I assume the id array is longer than `4`, which will be longer than the amount of items of `indirizzo`, thus resulting in undefined

```
for (var a = 0; a < ids.length; a++) {
```

Comment: right how would I solve it? -1 anywhere?

Comment: You should use something like this  ``` for(var x=0;x<indirizzo.length;x++){console.log(indirizzo[x]);}```

Comment: I've been told The geocoder is asynchronous

Comment: got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480896/1018804